# Parallel Query Processing in a specific stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have read about Parallelism in an oracle focused book, where they mention that you can do something like `ALTER TABLE Order PARALLEL 3;` My question is:

If I have a query that retrieves data based on a search and I want to add some parallelism to it how would I go about that in Microsoft SQL Server?  For instance:

```
ALTER PROC MY_SP
@SOMEPARAMETER NVARCHAR(2000)
AS

  SELECT DESCRIPTION 
    FROM ORDERS 
   WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%' + @SOMEPARAMETERHERE +'%'
```

How could I implement parallelism to this query?

**NOTE:** Excuse if syntax error, its just an example of what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I think you want to read about [MAXDOP](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/15/sql-server-maxdop-settings-to-limit-query-to-run-on-specific-cpu/)

Comment: You should trust the optimizer - if it wants to use parallelism, it will (admittedly, it used to be quite bad at parallelizing queries, but it's been getting better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Parallelism is determined by two values, the Max Degree of Parallelism (MAXDOP) and the Cost Threshold for Parallelism. The MAXDOP can be set at the server level as a default value and you can use a query hint. Setting the MAXDOP to 0 means that the SQL Server optimizer will consider using as many parallel processses as it can if the query passes the Cost Threshold for Parallelism. If you set the MAXDOP to 1, it more or less removes parallelism from the options. Any other number acts as a limit, so if you have, for example 4 processors, but you set the MAXDOP to 2, then only two will be used for any given query (not the same two necessarily, just two).

The real kicker is the cost threshold for parallelism. The default value is 5, which is frankly too low. Parallel execution of queries is a very expensive operation, splitting the threads, processing everything, gathering the threads back together, so you want it to only run on expensive queries. For an OLTP system, I'd suggest bumping this value up to 40 and test from there. For a reporting system I'd also suggest bumping the value up to 25 and testing from that point.

Your query, with no JOINs and a simple, albeit non-sargeable, WHERE clause, is probably going to have a very low estimated cost. It's unlikely that it will exceed 1, but if you just want to experiment with parallelism, take a look at the execution plan for the query to determine if it's cost is more than 1. If it is, lower your cost threshold down to 1 and provide a MAXDOP hint for the query. You should then see parallel execution. But observe how fast that runs and how many resources it uses and compare it to the non-parallel execution. You want to be sure it's going to work for you in a positive manner.